# Append a line to end of sshd.conf

Tags: bash, user-data

Trying to append an entry to the last line of sshd.conf however it appends it to the end of the previous line.

```
echo -e "DenyGroups $(echo ${admin_membership_ad_group} | cut -f2 -d= |cut -f1 -d,|awk '{print tolower($0)}')" >> /etc/ssh/sshd.conf
```

and

```
echo "\nDenyGroups $(echo ${admin_membership_ad_group} | cut -f2 -d= |cut -f1 -d,|awk '{print tolower($0)}')" >> /etc/ssh/sshd.conf
```

Expectation:

```
Lastline
DenyGroups somegroup
```

Result:

```
LastlineDenyGroups somegroup
```

Comment: Expectation is Lastline and DenyGroup should be printed on the new line.

Comment: `awk -F '[=,]' '{print ORS tolower($2)}' <<<"$admin_membership_ad_group" >>'/etc/ssh/sshd.conf'`

Comment: It’s funny, the line with -e misses the newline escape and the line with the newline escape misses the -e switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last command you have forgotten the `-e`, see the test below:

```
$ # Create test file
$ echo -n LastLine > tst
$ # See what happens if you forget -e
$ echo -n '\n + echo without -e' >> tst
$ # Now add -e
$ echo -e "\nDenyGroups $(echo admin_membership_ad_group)" >> tst
$ # See the results
$ cat tst
LastLine\n + echo without -e
DenyGroups admin_membership_ad_group
```

Note that in the other shells builtin `echo` behaves differently. For instance in `zsh` the expansion of `\n` will happen even without specifying the `-e` option.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i '$a DenyGroups '"${admin_membership_ad_group}" /etc/ssh/sshd.conf
```

> `$`: refers to the last line
>
> `a`: append